# Angular4 template reference variable assignment

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've come across [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples) where we can see:

```html
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
```

I can't find any reference to the `="mdMenu"` part of this template [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-).

Is there some meaning to this or is it just a mistake on the example?

Comment: In the docs you've just linked to, note `#heroForm="ngForm"` - per the linked form docs, *"The variable heroForm is now a reference to the NgForm directive that governs the form as a whole."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc `[mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu"` refers to `<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">`

and in `#menu="mdMenu"`, mdMenu is the directive exported from Material.