# What does template reference variable assignment do? <span #mytrv="cdkOverlayOrigin">

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581046/angular4-template-reference-variable-assignment), but it doesn't explain what's going on with assignments to template reference vaiables...

I'm making a toolbar with dropdown menus using `@angular/cdk`'s `OverlayModule`.

In order to have multiple dropdown menus, I have to assign the `cdkOverlayOrigin` directive to it's template reference variable.

```
<span #mytrv1="cdkOverlayOrigin">...<span> 
<span #mytrv2="cdkOverlayOrigin">...<span>
```

so that I can access them individually with a `@ViewChild` of type `CdkOverlayOrigin`

```
@ViewChild('mytrv1') mytrv1: CdkOverlayOrigin;
@ViewChild('mytrv2') mytrv2: CdkOverlayOrigin;
```

It seems odd to me to assign a directive to a variable like this `#mytrv1="cdkOverlayOrigin"`. **Can anyone explain this pattern?**

Comment: `#foo` creates a temple reference to the host element. `#foo="bar"` creates a template reference to the directive `bar`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250259/what-is-auto-attribute-here-and-why-it-is-required